# three.js: texture on shapegeometry

Tags: three.js

I'm working with three.js and I have a plane shape. This shape should get a texture. Below you can see how I try this. The problem is, that the texture is only shown in two stripes at two edges of the shape. If I take higher values for texture.repeat this stripes get thinner. 
I know there is a related topic here [Three.JS Is it possible to render a texture on shapeGeometry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745168/three-js-is-it-possible-to-render-a-texture-on-shapegeometry/15746373#15746373), but I can't understand how that could help me.

```
    //Draw Floorshape
    var points_floor = [];

    points_floor.push(new THREE.Vector2(edges[edges.length-1][edges[3].length-1][0], edges[edges.length-1][edges[3].length-1][1]));
    for (var i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < edges[i].length; j++) {
            points_floor.push(new THREE.Vector2(edges[i][j][0], edges[i][j][1]));
        }
    }

    var shape_floor = new THREE.Shape(points_floor);

    var floorGeometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape_floor);
    var texture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("./img/tileable_wood_texture_by_ftIsis_Stock.jpg");
    texture.repeat.set(0.1, 0.1);
    texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

    var materialFloor = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map : texture,
        side : THREE.DoubleSide
    });

    var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, materialFloor);
    floor.overdraw = true;
```